# Html5 Dropdown get text reults as NaN

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got a dropdown Menu which is done in php and looks like this:

```
function HowDangerIsAProduct(){
        $howDangerIsAProductInNumbers = array("secure","mostly Secure","very Danger");

        $stringchain = '<select class="form-control" id="HowDangerIsaProduct" name="HDIAP">';
        $stringchain .= '<option disabled="disabled">How Danger would you rate that product</option>';



        foreach ($howDangerIsAProductInNumbers as $hdiapin)
        {
            $stringchain .= '<option>'
                 .$hdiapin
                 .'</option>';
        }

        $stringchain .= '</select>';

        return $strinchain;
    }
```

Now the user should choose one option and I want to get the text, so i build up some javascript/jQuery code to fetch the selected text:

```
$('#HowDangerIsaProduct').change(function(){
    Impact =  + $(this).text();
});
```

I also tried `.val()` but its result is always `NaN`
But if I put numbers in the array (e.g. 1,2,3,4)it works fine but I want to save the text to a database.

Got any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: so you want to convert .text() to a number?

Comment: `.val()`, not `.text()`. you're using `.text()` on a `<select>`. that won't get you the value of the selected option, it'll get any text nodes INSIDE the select.

Comment: no i just want to get the selected textvalue like secure, mostly Secure or very Danger. but it result in NaN

Comment: @Sires remove `+` before `$(this)`

Comment: Look like it works now, Thanks Could you explain why i need it on numbers ?

Comment: @Sires upvote and accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Impact =  + $(this).text();
```

will return Nan because you are trying make a string integer positive.

Therefore simply remove `+` before the string and make it:

```
Impact =  $(this).text();
```

*Note:
if text was a number use parseInt to a `Number` first.*

```
Impact =  + parseInt($(this).text())
```